# How to get query results only with the latest date?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to make a query which will show me all the orders that happened before today. And I have achieved it with this query

```
SELECT tblOrder.date, tblOrder.name
FROM tblOrder
WHERE (((tblOrder.date)<=Date()))
GROUP BY  tblOrder.date, tblOrder.name
```

And the output would be:

```
-------------------
-  Date  -Name    -  
-------------------
-02.06.16-Company1-
-23.06.16-Company2-
-24.06.16-Company1-
-------------------
```

My question is how do I make a query which would only show Company1 once (group by of some sort) with the last date so I would not see the same company twice.

Output that I would like to have:

```
-------------------
-  Date  -Name    -  
-------------------
-23.06.16-Company2-
-24.06.16-Company1-
-------------------
```

I was trying grouping by only by name only the name but as I have found out it was not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GROUP BY name` and ask for the `Max(date)` within each group.

```sql
SELECT o.name, Max(o.date) AS latest_order_date
FROM tblOrder AS o
WHERE o.date <= Date()
GROUP BY o.name;
```

Comment: Thanks, where does the o.* comes from. After i added it, it asks for an input

Comment: I made `o` an [alias](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-SQL-FROM-clause-2a7d031c-6912-4e8c-a644-590940ddaed1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1#bm2) for the table name ... `FROM tblOrder AS o` ... so elsewhere in the query, `o.` means `tblOrder.`

Comment: When you test that query in the query designer, what is the input Access is looking for?  The parameter input dialog includes the "name" of whatever Access considers to be the parameter.

Comment: I've figured it out , had to change some names, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `where` clause.  Assuming no dates are duplicated:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM tblOrder as o
WHERE o.date = (SELECT MAX(o2.date)
                FROM tblOrder as o2
                WHERE o2.name = o.name AND o2.date <= Date()
               );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `distinct`

```
SELECT distinct tblOrder.name, tblOrder.date
FROM tblOrder
WHERE (((tblOrder.date)<=Date()))
GROUP BY  tblOrder.date, tblOrder.name
```

Comment: Now you can remove the group by! However, still not what OP is asking for.

Comment: Also you can remove the group by